# How to fix twilio outbound call error 12100?

Tags: twilio

I am trying to implement a CRM integration of twilio with javascript code to call an external number using Twilio client 
 but am getting an exception saying connection declined. Twilio debugger error is attached in the snapshot. What's surprising is that incoming calls come through on the same client when called from an external number.

Just before calling Twilio.device.connect(params), I have checked the status of the device and I can see that it is ready.

Chrome developer tools throws exception like below. I have searched everywhere but haven't been able to get to the bottom of it as the error in task router as well as chrome developer tools is not very helpful.

Can someone please help me find out what the error is? Or at least point me in the right direction to debug this error?

Uncaught (in promise) Error: {"code":9003,"message":"SKfd3715cc954ce7920622fe6845425f02 is invalid"}
    at XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange (Twilio.min.js:55)

[image: Twilio Debugger snapshot]

$("#phone-call").click(function () {
alert(Twilio.Device.status());

params = {"PhoneNumber": '0424599908',To: '0424599908'};
 Twilio.Device.connect(params);

```
   });
```

Comment: Are you pointing the client to TwiML, when they make an outbound call?

Comment: No I am not pointing to TwiML. Javascript initialisation at the beginning handles device setup.

$(function () {
    {
        /** This encloses all the code for outgoing calls**/


 
            var token;
        $.getJSON('CRM webhook').done(function (data) {

            token = data.token;
            alert(data.identity);
            // Setup Twilio.Device
            Twilio.Device.setup(data.token);

Comment: Point the TwiML Application (Voice) Request URL to a TwiML Source. https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/client/javascript